# Cannot extend partition to unallocated space

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I deleted a partition in hopes to extend the primary partition, but Windows simply won’t let me do it:

[image]

UPDATE: found a solution using diskpart at http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-format-your-SD-card-back-to-the-original-si/

Comment: Try adding a new volume onto the unallocated space and see if you can then extend the other volume. You could also try a linux LiveCD to extend the partition if Windows still refuses!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot extend, move a partition while its in use (Active), it requires an unmount of the drive altogether.

Just use a LiveCD or bootable USB with a usb utility such as [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/liveusb.php). (GParted comes pre-installed in any Ubuntu Live CD)

---

[Partitioning With GParted Without Losing Data](http://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted)

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems like it may not be relevant in this case, there is another reason that you can't extend a partition into unallocated space.

If the partition you want to extend is a logical drive inside an **extended** partition, then the Disk Management GUI isn't clever enough to expand that extended partition automatically into the unallocated space, so it thinks there isn't enough space to extend the logical drive that is inside it.

To solve this, use `diskpart` from an admin command prompt, select the correct volume and then use the `extend` command, as explained here: https://superuser.com/a/851382/79763