# Cannot extend partition

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I am trying to extend volume in windows using Disk Management.I came across this:

> "Extend Volume" is grayed out. The reason is that
>   you can extend a partition in Disk Management only under the condition that
>   there is adjacent unallocated space.

But even after making the partition and the unallocated space contiguous i cannot extend my existing partition. (Extend partition is greyed out why and what should i do?)

Why cant i extend volume even if the unallocated space is right next to the partition i want to extend.

Why is extend volume greyed out still?

[image]

P.S I found [this](https://superuser.com/a/851387/851297)  but couldn't completely understand it can someone explain this to me.

Thanks!

Comment: You would have to delete your extended partition in order to make this possible.  The reason you cannot extend your extended partition is due to the fact, the unallocated partition is not parted of your extended partition.

Comment: which extended partition are you talking about and how do i know if a partition is extended partition.Pardon my ignorance i dont know much about this thing.

Comment: `Partition Manager` itself indicates which partition is an Extended partition.  You have 2 Primary partitions and 1 Extended partition.  Due to the fact you are likely using MBR you can only have 3 Primary partitions.

Comment: MBR can have 4 primary partitions, I believe an extended partition counts as one of them. Anyway, I thought gparted can resize an extended partition, and then the partition & ntfs filesystem in your D: drive

Answer (score 1):

It's an MBR drive, so it can contain at most 4 top-level partitions. These can be:

- up to 4 *primary partitions*, or
- up to 3 *primary partitions* and an *extended partition*
- the *extended partition* can contain any number of *logical drives*.

You have:

1. Two primary partitions (navy)
2. An extended partition (green border)

   - Contains one logical drive (blue)
3. Unallocated space (black)

You're trying to resize the logical drive. Logical drives must be contained in the extended partition. There's no more space in your extended partition, so you can't extend the logical drive.

#### Solution

Extend the extended partition into unallocated space. This will make unallocated space available for the logical drive.

Comment: But the problem is - as described in the question - you can't extend the extended partition in the UI. The option is grayed out. The solution is to use diskpart.
See here: https://superuser.com/questions/851360/cannot-extend-non-system-bitlocker-partition/851382#851382